# How to move a complex object to the origin without destroying it?

Tags: objects, coordinates

I have a complex object far away from the origin of the scene itself.

If I mark all parts and use the `Geometry to Origin` function, the complex object gets crumbled, because all parts are set at the origin and the relations are destroyed.

Is there a way to move the object as a whole?

The object was an import from an [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into edit mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> and *Cursor to selected*.

Then go back to object mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, *Origin to cursor*, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> (clear location).

Answer (score 4):

If you need to **keep the origin in the same place**, you can select the object, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected*. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *> Origin to Geometry* and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Selection to cursor*. **You do not need to be in edit mode at any time to do this**, and the origin will end up in the same place, just with the mesh centered around it.

Also you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *> Origin to Geometry* or any of the other options, just this one command has the same result as Christy James process.

Comment: I do not have the option `Origin to Center of Geometry`

Comment: @Wandang It is just plain `Origin to Geometry` then, does the same thing

Comment: This is better than my answer actually, I thought that 'origin to geometry' and 'geometry to origin' did the same thing but backwards, but evidently not!

Answer (score 3):

1. Add an empty <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty* > *Plain Axes*, then position it at the proper position to your object with <kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Select all the pieces of your object, then select the empty last.
3. [Parent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) the object(s) to the empty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Object*.
4. Select just the empty and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to clear the location, which moves it to the scene origin.

**Optional step** if you do not want your object(s) parented to a empty

5. Again select both the empty and your object(s), then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*. If you want to, you can now delete the empty.

[image: animated gif of moving objects to the origin process]

Answer (score 2):

Or, in edit mode, select all <kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> > *cursor to center*
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> > *selection to cursor (offset)*