# How do I move an object using WASD (like walk mode)

Tags: objects, 3d-view, transforms

Using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> you can move around using WASD and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> lets you have gravity which is good. How might I utilize this with objects. Locking to camera lets me do this but simply selecting an object does not let me do this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to [parent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> the object you want to move to the active camera.

A few quirks about parented objects and walk mode: Make sure the object is not intersecting the camera; if it is the camera will fly away when the gravity is turned on. By default the object will inherent all the rotation from the camera, use *Vertex* parenting (in my linked [parenting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) answer) if the rotation is not wanted.

Switch the view to camera view <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>, then enter walk mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.
When you are done "walking around" your scene press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that will move the camera to the place where you ended walk mode. Because the object is parented to the camera it will move along with the camera.

You should unparent <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> the object from the camera after you are done.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: This seems to work, thanks, my only other question is how might I make my object clip surfaces as opposed to phasing through them?

Comment: The hotkey has changed to `shift` + `\``(grave) to enter walk mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch your view to wireframe so you can see through your object, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> you can view throught he objects perspective. you can now <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to move the object, just be sure to set your render view back to your camera later.

Comment: note: gravity doesn't work.