# Rotate whole animation by 90 degrees

Tags: animation

I make my animation and now I realized that its pointed in wrong direction I used -y (native blender) as direction but I need to be pointed at x axis so what would be the easiest way to rotate whole animation, to switch -y with x :)

Comment: Could you rotate your camera? Maybe rotate the final result in the compositor?

Comment: No I cant, Im need to export animation for game :)

Answer (score 12):

1. On the first frame add an empty at the same location as your object.  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then add the empty with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty*.
2. [Parent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) the object or objects to the new empty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).
3. Rotate the empty by 90° along the Z axis.

Answer (score 0):

While being in Pose Mode, the following worked magically for me.
For some reason, when I change the Rotation value, the rotation is applied to all key frames:

[image]