# Rotation animation on z-axis in Blender

Tags: animation, keyframes, mirror

I am  quite new to blender and it is first time I am making a character and an animation with it in blender.

I have a rabbit character that I gave some animation keyframe so it has an idle animtion, a walk animation and a jump animation.
I want to use this character later in Unity for a little game. I want to make a side view game, so the character can for example can walk to right and left. I do not know if you can flip/mirror the animaiton in Unity. 
In blender I want to make an animation where it walks from right to left, and then an animation where it walks from left to right.

I tried changing the position of the character by rotating the whole armature on the z-axis to 180, and I hoped with the auto-keyframes turned on it would create new keyframes automaticly with the new location and rotation of the armature but as I play the animation it changed the whole animation to be 180 on the z-axis, so the whole animation was flipped. It did'nt work as I would love to. 
I then tried to create a new Action and copy the keyframes and then do the 180-thing on the z-axis, but it also changed the characters position on the other Action...

I do not know what to do from now on.
I just want the character and keyframes to be flipped, so I get an animation that both walks from right til left, and left to right.

Hope you guys will help me!

**Update**

I tried to look at this question [Rotate whole animation by 90 degrees](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28276/rotate-whole-animation-by-90-degrees)

But this did not help, I could rotate it by using an empty cube and parenting it to the objects, but it still rotates the whole animation.
I have an animation where it walks from right to left and i like to keep that, I just want an animation from there on that walk the opposite way from left to right by just rotating the object and armature and make keyframes of that.

Comment: thank you for linking that question, I tried, but it was not quiet what I wanted. I updated the question.

Comment: @Alex378 It's hard to say without seeing the animation in graph editor. You probably can mirror Z rotation and X,Y location curves of the origin to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

- Suggestion. Select armature in object mode. Go to  start frame 02. Insert Key frame rotation.  Go to end frame 08. Rotate armature on Z-axis. Insert key frame rotation. Test Animation.
- Consider watching a tutorial video on a video website.  There are some really useful introductory tutorials on the web.  Search Blender Tutorial Keyframes.