# How can I constrain a camera to focus on a face of an object?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, camera

I have an object that I want the camera focus all time on the same face.

So if I move or rotate the object and so the face too, the camera should move/rotate to continue focusing the same face. 
Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Does this help - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/constraint-the-camera-to-look-at-an-object ?

Comment: Also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28621/make-camera-system-look-at-empty

Comment: As you want to stay focused on the same part of the object I would think parenting the camera to the object would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have doing this suggestion :
[Constrain camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/constraint-the-camera-to-look-at-an-object)

But that solution is just make the camera only looking to the center of the object, not the face you want.

The next step you need is just to create a vertex group on the face you want then assign it to the constraint :

1. Select your target object and go to edit mode.
2. Select your designed face.
3. Go to the mesh data tab and in the vertex group field, just add one by click + button.
4. Rename your vertex group and click assign ( to assign the face you selected )
5. Then select your camera, go to the constraint tab, and insert your vertex group to the vertex group field

Comment: Following all the steps, the problem is that the camera is fixed into a point and don't shown the selected face all time. Any way to fix it?