# Camera following a flying paper

Tags: camera

I am a noob to Blender but I decided to give it a try only recently so bear with me.

I am trying to render out a simple flying paper simulation. I have done that using soft body and collision to the pane and blew it with wind and turbulence.

Now the problem is I cant get all of its simulation with my camera. So I thought to have the camera follow it from the side as it flies by to capture the wind folds of the paper, but I just cant get it done.

I have tried parenting with empty, constraints. I have been researching on it for last 5 hours already but i just cant find the solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check out this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28621/make-camera-system-look-at-empty

Comment: The paper is moving fast due to a strong wind and it also falls off. So with this will the camera follow in both X and Y?  I will try that out and let you know. Thanks