# Blender Bullet Camera Animation

Tags: animation, camera

I have modelled a bullet and want to make a camera animation around the bullet.
I want it to like this: [First bullet animation starts at 4 seconds](https://youtu.be/Bel011-6o4Y?t=4)

I managed to get the bullet to spin, added a camera and used keyframes but I just cant get it to look right. Any tips on how to achieve the same effect?

Here's what I got right now: https://youtube.com/shorts/yAyjjqJZBjo?feature=share

Answer (score 1):

You have a good start with some of the basic key poses for the camera set. Now you want to work on smoothing out the motion. You'll want to spend some time reading about keyframe "[Interpolation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/introduction.html#interpolation)". Try editing your keyframes for the camera in [the Graph Editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHlln3AzeMs), change the frames to Bezier.

While this can work, it can be tricky to animate the camera to look where you want it to. You might consider adding an empty that the camera "looks at", and animate both the empty and the camera. Read how make the camera look at an object here: [Make Camera System Look at Empty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28621/make-camera-system-look-at-empty)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go.