# How to make objects "look bright" with a haze of light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I can make objects that emit light, but they never "look bright."

I want my lights to look like this:

[image: good bulb]

However, what I make looks like this:

[image: bad bulb]

This is the node setup:

[image: node setup]

There's no haze of light around it, and the only way you can even tell it's giving off light is if something's near it to reflect it.

How do I get that same haze that's around the light bulb?

Comment: You may do this in compositor using the Glare node. See related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31262/how-do-i-make-a-glowing-image-texture

Comment: I might add that the supplied images was ***heavily*** post-processed.

Comment: See the result of adding the Glare effect in my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33075/modelling-with-simple-deform

Comment: One of ways is by adding volumetric material to the area where bulb is placed. It would be much more noiser of course compared to the compositor method, so big amount of samples will be needed to make it clean (and maybe it'll make you turn to using compositor instead).

Comment: Okay, I'm using the Glare composition node, set to Fog Glow, and it looks pretty good, but I want to turn the Size up more. Blender locks to 9, though. Is there a way to override this and increase the glare?

Comment: @Somatic Play with a Threshold value. It should make the glow bigger.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing/35860#35860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried that but couldn't get a convincing result that reproduces the image but at least it could be a starting point.
For detailed material settings see the attached .blend.

[image]

Compositing adds the red glow:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you're using a MixRGB node set to 'Mix' - wouldn't it be better to use 'Add' instead? Also, you are just using the white of the ID Mask and then shifting the color to red, it looks like - that means you lose the original color of the glow. Try masking in the yellow glow object instead of the glass (or even try volume emission, but that's another topic) - then use the mask data to bring back in that original color and blur *the color*. Is this making sense? I'd like to put together a proper answer at some point, but have no time at the moment. :-/

Comment: @Mentalist thanks for your suggestions. I used volume emission but had problems to create the mask. The blend is attached, feel free to improve and add another answer. Modifing is probably not as time consuming as to recreateit  from scratch.

Comment: Thanks :-)  [Here is a .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/818/) I threw together after experimenting a bit with the concepts I mentioned in my first comment. It's far from perfect, but hopefully helpful to study. Once again, short on time / can't guide you through how it works at the moment... but it's a start.

Comment: @Mentalist Thanks! This looks great don't you want to add this as an answer? Just the rendered image  and the .blend

Comment: @Somatic Check out the above .blend by mentalist this looks awesome.

Answer (score 3):

An approach using shaders gets this result:
[image: Bulb with glow]

The trick is to create a material which mixes translucent, diffuse, and glass shaders.

---

1. Build a scene like this. It has a backdrop, a bulb and a filament.

[image: scene]

2. Put the filament inside the bulb:

[image: filament]

3. Create a shader for the background:

[image: backdrop shader]

4. Create a shader for the filament:

[image: filament shader]

5. Create a shader for the bulb. The geometry input is used to control where the bulb will be translucent, diffuse, or glass. The 'backfacing' geometry input is used to make the interior of the bulb act like a diffuse surface and reflect the filament light. When not 'backfacing', the the bulb surface is translucent. (See [How can I make a material only apply to a side of a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane) and [How to create a mirror shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23913/how-to-create-a-mirror-shader) ) This is not enough to make it appear to glow. The geometry input for 'normal' and 'incoming' is used with the cross product to determine if the camera is looking at the center of the bulb or the edge. At the edge, a glass shader is used, towards the center, the translucent/diffuse shader is used.

[image: bulb shader]

---

The blend file is here: [image]