# About Glass Material of a Bulb Object

Tags: rendering

for first time i gave it a try to make a bulb in Blender. But glass of the bulb has some white noisy and strong areas as in the picture. Do you know how can i fix it ?[image]

And here is the material node set i used
[image]

Comment: to have less noise youi need more samples  see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: also look through this related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/light-bulb-filaments-brightness-and-internal-reflections-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43810/how- and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellowto-make-objects-look-bright-with-a-haze-of-light and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/noisy-pixelated-lightbulb-filament-emitter/77304#77304

Comment: You should be using a Math node instead of the Mix RGB node - as it stands it will be acting more like an Average node - try Maths Add, Max, Min in that situation instead. Also, is your glass modelled as a solid piece with the element embedded in it or does the glass have a thickness? Try adding a solidify modifier model the inner and outer surfaces manually.

Comment: I added inner and outer thickness to it. Also changed it with Maths and tried Add, Max and Min. Still same. Does it have anything to do with environment lights ?