# duplicating a surface and making it a child node

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, parent

I would like to copy a surface from a rounded cube and make it a child node of the rounded cube. This image depicts what I mean.

[image]

The black square represents the surface that I want to duplicate and add to the cube as a child node. I'm really new to Blender and I appreciate any help I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Duplicate, separate and parent

To get the surface you'll have to duplicate the faces.

[image]  [image]

Enable Edit Mode, select the faces you need, duplicate them by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.
Your new faces shall now be selected, but they still belong to the cube object.

To separate them press <kbd>p</kbd> while the faces are still selected. Choose "Separate" in the pop up menu to tell blender that you want to put those faces in a different object with "selection" criteria.

Now that you have two diffeent object you can [parent with hierarchy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects).

Comment: okay that worked great. Where to I set the node hierarchy?

Comment: See the second paragraph (start from "The 3D view"..) of this [related answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects)