# How to I merge two objects so I can move them around as if they were one object?

Tags: modeling

I've seen other questions about merging objects, usually involving deleting faces from both of them and connecting them together. But that's not what I want. I just want to be able to control many objects together, using scale, movement, etc, as if it was only one object.

Does anyone know how to do this? It seems like it should be easy but I haven't found a good explanation yet..

Comment: [Parenting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217)

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do that.
One option is to select all the objects and **join** them into one (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>).

Another option is to **parent** all of your objects to one of the objects or to an empty.

Affecting the parent_object/empty will affect all of them, but you can still edit/re-arrange each one of them individually.

[image]