# Is there a setting to outline child objects when the parent is selected?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, selection-tools, parent

I'm still newish to blender.
Is there a setting to outline child objects when the parent is selected?
In Maya, when you select a parent object, all the children objects are highlighted as well.
In Blender, only the selected object gets outlined.  So far the only way I know how to outline all the child objects is by "Shift + G" or "Select Hierarchy".  This way isn't very efficient if you have a large scene with lots of groups and you want to quickly see all the children objects of each group down the outliner.

Is there a setting to outline/highlight child objects when the parent is selected, without having to actually select the entire hierarchy?

Comment: I don't know if you can highlight only but you can select the children, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42369/is-there-a-way-to-select-the-children-of-a-parent-object