# What are these black axes lines on my model?

Tags: modeling, objects

I am trying to deconstruct this mess of a file I downloaded from TurboSquid, I think it was made in Blender Render, in order to reconstruct it in Cycles and I just do not know what these things are.

[image]

Comment: These are Empties. Learn more about them here: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/empties.html

Comment: My first guess is that they are used in some form of rig for the mesh

Comment: "Empties".. hmm. They are very bizarre. I don't get it. Because when I turn the eye icon to off nothing happens... the object it's attached to still shows up in the modeling window... but if I right click on the name and choose delete, then whatever part it's attached to deletes.  So obviously they aren't THAT empty because they somehow hold an object. :) Sorry. Thanks for the link. I'll try to make sense of it.

Comment: @Marc read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those axis you see are [empties](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/empties.html?highlight=empty) (or Null Objects).

quote from the manual:

> Empties can serve as transform handles which cannot be edited and do not render. Empties are important and useful objects. Some examples of ways to use them include: Parent object for a group of objects
>
> An Empty can be parented to any number of other objects - This gives the user the ability to control a group of objects easily, and without affecting a render.
>   Target for constraints
>
> An empty can also be used as a target for normal, or bone constraints.
>   This gives the user far more control; for instance, a rig can easily be set up to enable a camera to point towards an empty using the Track to constraint
>   Array offset
>
> An empty can be used to offset an array modifier, meaning complex deformations can be achieved by only moving a single object.

An empty by itself would show on the outliner window like this, with nothing else:

[image]

An empty that has something parented to it will show what kind of objects is a parent of:

[image]

In your case the empties are controlling something, meshes or other objects.
To find out what that might be click on the Plus (+) sign on the left to expand the tree list (hierarchy).

[image]

Comment: This YouTube video was also helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuGc12SVEYw