# How can i make two objects move together?

Tags: animation

how can i make 2 objects move together? i am creating a Minecraft animation, and need the sword to move with my hand. I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, yet it still doesnt move together

Comment: Ctrl + G groups objects, not the same as creating a parent -> child relationship, more like siblings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linking the objects by making one of the two objects the parent. If you select both objects you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and make the last selected object the *Parent*.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects