# How to create child-of constraint

Tags: constraints, parent

I've looked all over the internet and found plenty of information on child-of constraints, but no site actually tells me how to make one. How are constraints made?

Comment: related: https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/interface/adding_removing.html  and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects/26109#26109

Answer (score 1):

Select your object. Go to the the contsraints section of the properties window and add Child of constraint.Then select what object you want to use as target.

[image]

more info here: https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html?highlight=child