# Linking an object to a flying camera

Tags: rendering, camera

I want to link one of the objects in my scene to be linked with a flying camera and render it. I am looking for a simplified Call of Duty style, which can be watched [in the youtube video here](https://youtu.be/UKC9aUDYr3w?t=9s), where the gun or other tools can always be seen in the hand of the player.

My scene includes a large cave and I want to attach a stick to a flying camera inside the cave so that when I move the camera I can always see a *small tip* of the stick *oriented with a fixed angle* with respect to the camera in the rendered video. I want to fly the camera to look at the top, bottom, and side walls of the cave while walking towards the end of the cave. I would be grateful for any tip.

Comment: You can read about parenting right here ... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects ... it's highly recommended that you do a search before posting a question.

Comment: @hawkenfox, thank you, I did a search using keywords linking objects and camera but I did not know about parenting, which seems like a great idea. Thank you.

Comment: No problem then, cheers.