# How do you group objects together without joining them?

Tags: mesh, groups, versions

In Photoshop you can create a folder and put all the layers under that folder. This makes them easier to manage. How do I do this in Blender?

I'm not looking to do a boolean union or grouping them. I don't understand what the point of ctrl-g group is honestly. It would be nice to have something like the photoshop folder that enables me to manipulate multiple objects at a time, cleans up my hierarchy view, and doesn't join stuff together. Any help? I know this is probably super basic but I can't find it looking online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many ways to do this, if you group objects together you can then add a group instance of that group, this is an empty that controls all the geometry in that group.

Alternatively you could use an empty, parent everything to it and then disable the ability to interact with the objects.

You can also just parent everything to an object of your choice, probably the biggest one of the group, and control everything that way.

It depends what your objective is by grouping.

Comment: Okay I was looking through the documentation and I saw the stuff about parenting. Are there specific best practices for that? Based on pipeline or animation tool use norms? Also, how exactly do I do that? I kept trying to click and drag one object on top of another in hierarchy to get it to become a child and that didn't do anything.

Comment: Have a look at the link Duarte posted up there too, parenting cannot be done in a drag and drop fashion, tough I guess that could be a pretty good suggestion.

To parent select all the objects you wish to parent and last the parent hit ctrl+P and select object, when it comes to best practices I'm not aware of any, just keep your workspace tidy, and make hierarchys that make sense, for example, it makes sense for a "table" object to be the parent of some "magazine" objects, not the other way around.

And this is personal preference, but abuse empty objects.

Comment: It's possible to parent with drag and dropping object to be child to the object to be parent in the Outliner, see Outliner section [in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/1245). However it might not act as expected in some cases especially without enough practice so it's best to start with usual ways like Ctrl+P and stuff.