# How do i change just one side of a mirrored model?

Tags: modeling, mirror

I'm working on a model of a cat and i wanted to give it an earring on one side and a cut in the ear on the other. The problem is i've only created one half of the model and used the mirror modifier. so how will i be able to change one side?

Comment: I can think of a couple of options: **Apply the mirror modifier** to make all of your geometry real, or use the earring as a **different object** and make it a child object of the cat. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't know i had to apply the modifier.

Comment: Please don't mark the question as "Solved". If any of the answers worked for you mark it as accepted. Otherwise in the site the question remains tagged as ''unanswered''. If you solved your issue in a different way, then write an answer detailing what you did and accept your own answer. Please read through the following links to understand how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/answering

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break symmetry you have to remove the *Mirror* modifier by clicking *Apply*. Unfortunately once I'ts done you can't go back, so be sure that your cat has enough details before you apply the modifier.

Another way to do that to keep the mirror modifier would be to add another modifier on the stack, over the mirror modifier. In your case, you could add a *Boolean* modifier to make the cut, but think to hide this modifier if you want to edit the base mesh if it is high poly, it can slow down blender.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the half and mirror the duplicate with **Ctrl M** And if you use the modifier with Merge checked you get **one** mesh

Answer (score -1):

They easy solution which i have found is to go in edit mode and select the vertices you want to change and move them to where ever you want them to be

Comment: This won't work when the mirror modifier is still there, as it'll mirror the changes. OP specifically asks about creating non-mirrored changes.