# I want to "unmirror" a model

Tags: mirror

So, I have a 3D model torso. I made only half of the body, and then used the mirror modifier to generate the other half. However, now I want to modify it asymetrically. How can I turn off the mirror modifier, and still keep the other half?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i change just one side of a mirrored model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86226/how-do-i-change-just-one-side-of-a-mirrored-model)

Comment: Possibly not helpful, depending on what you're really wanting to do, but if what you want is to be able to toggle symmetry off, do some edits, and turn it back on again, the closest thing to that in Blender that I know if is the use of the symmetry function in Sculpt mode. It allows asymetric features to be added, and then to have symmetry turned back on again afterwards, without losing the asymmetric results. Of course, you can't manipulate individual vertices in Edit Mode this way. Edit Mode only ever knows the base version of your mesh, never the presently modified one.

Answer (score 2):

just apply the mirror modifier. Then it is a "real" mesh on both sides and you can modify it asymetrically.

[image]