# How to attach a mesh to another mesh

Tags: modeling

Started using blender a week ago, so im kinda new. And i have no idea how to do this properly. I've got 2 cubes, one which is going to be an house, and another cube that i want to make the porch. So i would like to attach that to the main building. I've got no idea how to do it, and found nothing around the net about it. Any help?

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by attach? like, do you want them to be touching each other or be sharing vertices...? what should the finished outcome be like?

Comment: Sharing vertices yes.

Comment: select both and press Ctrl + J, or look up [parenting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26108/2217).

Comment: Yeah thats what i found online. But in the picture i have already done that. Is there anyway to make them merge into eachother. Should have probaly said this in the start, sorry forgot :) EDIT: Overlooked the link about parenting, thats exactly what i want. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

I am a little late on this, but there is another way I find useful. Two have been mentioned here - merging the objects and parenting one object to another.

---

**Merging** is done by selecting both objects and pressing Ctrl + J. Objects become a single object sharing vertices, editable at the same time in Edit mode. In a way, this is a very **one way operation** - working with the objects separatedly after they have been merged can be difficult.

---

**Parenting** the objects **affects object hierarchy**, here is an Icosphere parented to a cube:

[image: Parented object hierarchy]

---

If you for some reason don't want this hierarchy, you can use **Object Constraint** with the name of `Child Of`. Here, I have a Car that has two sets of tires "childed" to it via the Object Constraint:

[image: Object Constraint - Child of - object hierarchy]

As far as I can see, it behaves the same as the *Parent* action, except for the object hierarchy it creates. If you want to prevent excessive object nesting, this seems like a pretty good way to me.

I'm using Blender 2.92

Answer (score 1):

You may try that

1. Select both objects, hit Ctrl + J
2. Select the two or more vertix you want to be combined
3. Hit Alt + M
4. From Pop up menu, may select, At First, At last etc as required

Best of luck !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to "merge" two object would be to select your object first, and select the object you want it to merge into second, and press CTRL+J. This will join both objects into a single object, thus sharing verts.

If you want to keep the two objects separate however, but share properties, do the same as above, but instead of pressing CTRL+J, press CTRL+P to parent the first object to the second one. You can also choose parent under the object tab (The one with the orange cube).

If you want the two objects to stay completely separate, but share some information, like location, you can use constraints (It's the tab with the chain icon).

Hope this helps.