# What would be the best way to put teeth on this model?

Tags: modeling

this is my first model and I need teeth for this character but im not sure how to go about it. The teeth on the shoulder pads are just planes that I shaped but they're missaligned and id like it to be way cleaner. Any tips?[image: Model of Susanoo I'm Making]

[[image: Picture of reference][2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Array modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html), could a good fit for this.

Try creating a curve along the jaw - where (human) gums would normally be. Then create a single tooth, add `Array` modifier to it. In `Fit Type` select `Fit curve`, pick your "gum curve". The modifier should create enough teeth to  cover the entire curve, but you can play with the spacing and number of clones. You will probably need to do this for the bottom jaw too.

*Sidenote: I suggest [parenting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86665/how-to-attach-a-mesh-to-another-mesh/249272#249272) the curves to your model, so when it moves, the teeth move with it.*