# blender making empty parent as a child in cube parent

Tags: objects, parent

Okay so I've been trying to make it so that an empty object will become a child in my cube parent object but I don't know how to make it become a child.

I've tried pressing shift to make the empty object into my cube parent but it doesn't make the empty parent become a child.

Comment: Select the Empty Object then SHIFT Select the Cube and press CTRL + "P" and select "Object" from the drop down menu.

Comment: not working man I tried that

Comment: Does shift have to be pressed at the same time when selecting the cube and for some reason ctrl+p doesn't bring up a menu. Does it have to be in object or edit mode?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to be done in Object Mode.

First select the object you want as a children (in your case, the empty). Hold SHIFT while you select the object you want to become the parent of the object you selected first (Note that the outline around your empty object should turn from a bright orange to a dark orange color).

Then press CTRL+P and select "Select parent to "Object"".

GIF illustrating the process:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To set the parent very fast go to the ***Outliner*** and drag the 'empty icon' of an *Empty* to the 'mesh icon' of the *Cube*. You may also unparent the objects in the same way. 
[image]