# Setting up an animation that will move a model relative to its last position

Tags: animation

I am very new to Blender, so sorry if this is an impossible question

I am trying to build a game of chess and want to create some animations for moving the pieces across the board.

But obviously, it would be impossible to do so on a one-by-one basis.

I want this to be an animation that I can export/save and run again and again to move my pieces.

So imagine a pawn. It moves one square at a time. Now I know how I can setup an animation with absolute co-oordinates, so I end up with 9 animations per pawn... but honestly it is an unscalable solution.

Imagine I am trying to do this with any of the more power pieces like the bishop, castle or queen. I would need to setup hundreds of animations.

What I want is an animation that will look at the current location and give me a new one relative to that everytime I run it. I don't want a script to do this, because I need to export the animation and I not sure I can export scripts.

Is this simply impossible...

Comment: and you want to export to what format?

Comment: did u try to use delta transformation? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109666/animate-location-and-scale-relative-to-starting-point

Comment: I am going to export them in USD format. Yes, I did look at delta transformations; but it doesn't seem to be a delta from the last value, but a delta from the already set animations.

Comment: Just tried the delta route again; definitively doesn't work. What about setting up some sort of parent-child thing... move child relative to parent; than parent. Next time when I move the child the parent will have a new location no? Would that work? Does it make sense?