# How can I unparent an object in an animaton?

Tags: animation, parent

I was working on a baby project in which a toy trains takes a block (typically a cube).

So I parented the block to the train and it moves perfectly from starting point to the stopping point.

At the stoping point I want this block to be un parented and start moving along a curve.

[image]

If I try to un parent it using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> its jumps around as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parenting can't be disabled during timeline. If you want this, you must use **Child Of** constraint instead. It has **influence** value, that can be animated.

[image]

Look also:

[How do I "parent" objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects/26109#26109)

[Dynamic parent addon](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?296018-WIP-Dynamic-Parent-addon)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, so how can I set child to un parent on a certain frame and keep the location same ?

Comment: Use two Child Of constraints. One is referencing the moving object and the other is referencing the static one. Animate the influences to obtain the desired effect.

Comment: @BlenderForYou see my links in answer

Comment: The Dynamic parent addon does not exist. The link is no good.