# Dynamic object parenting; Does it exist in Blender?

Tags: animation, constraints, parent

I would like to be able to dynamically parent and unparent an object to another object so that I can freely animate the parented object while it is not dynamically parented. Is their a way to do this in Blender?

Comment: You can animate a child-parent constrain. Is that what you need?

Comment: I did not want to use the Child Of constraint as I need to first parent a hat to a head which will spin around 180 degrees, and then a hand will remove the hat which means I effectively need 2 child of constraints, however I was not able to make this work. I thought it would be easier if I could just switch on and off a normal object parenting as required of hat parented to head.

Comment: See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92858/how-can-i-unparent-an-object-in-an-animaton/92859?r=SearchResults#92859