# how to generate square pyramids from the faces of a uv sphere

Tags: modeling

There was a time I was messing around with blender and found a way to generate rectangular pyramids (each as a separate object) from each of the faces of a uv sphere. I remember it was just a click and not a set of procedures. Now I need to use that for a rigid body animation but I don't remember what I did.

Does any one know what I need to do to get that effect again?

[image: each of the uv sphere's faces would generate a shape just like the one cut out in the picture]

Comment: I would like to point out that the geometric shape being used here is a *pyramid*, not a prism.

Comment: Yes you're right. It's a pyramid i want and not a square prism.

Comment: @BoluMorawo I *did* reread your question after you edited it, and it is still unclear. I have no idea what button you clicked.

Comment: If you want to get each pyramid as editable object then there're 2 ways. If using particle system then apply Particle System modifier and hide it or remove from emitter, if using duplifaces then select parent and press Ctrl+Shift+A to make copies as real objects. Resulting objects will be multi-user In both cases so if you want to edit them seperately use Make Single User command.

Answer (score 11):

Is this what you mean?
[image: spiky UV sphere]

1. Start with the entire UV sphere selected <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Poke the faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
3. Select just one of the new vertices. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > "*Amount of connecting edges*"  or from the 3D view header *Select* > *Select Similar* > "*Amount of connecting edges*". That will select the center vertex of each face.
4. Make sure the pivot point is set to *Median Point*, then scale <kbd>S</kbd> out.

Animated gif showing the above process.
[image: Animated gif showing how to make a spiky UV sphere]

---

Or maybe [DupliFaces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/duplifaces.html) is more like what you want?

1. Model the prism object.
2. Now [parent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) that to a UV sphere.
3. With the UV sphere selected. In the Object tab of the Properties window, scroll down to the *Duplication* section. Click on the *Faces* button.

[image: animated gif showing how to set up duplifaces]

Comment: You can also use particles.

Comment: No, this is not what i wanted actually. My question Has been edited please check it again.Thanks.

Comment: No-one has come back to read and answer my edited question.

Comment: @BoluMorawo With the dupliface approach you can easily turn each duplicate into a separate object with Ctrl+Shift+A (*Make Duplicates Real*). Is that what you have in mind?