# How to Remove this cross hair?

Tags: modeling

I downloaded a lamp model from Blendswap, but there is this big Cross hair which when I move, the entire object moves. It also get attached whenever I duplicate some part of the Lamp. How can I get rid of this?
[image]

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you so much @cegaton . God Bless

Answer (score 1):

That line indicates a parent child relationship.

Read: [How do I “parent” objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects/26109#26109) or The corresponding [Blender Manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html?highlight=parenting)

To [clear the relationship](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html?highlight=parenting#clear-parent) use **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>**