# Rookie Question : Is the body mesh the parent of the Rig?

Tags: modeling, rigging

Is the body mesh the parent of the Rig ? I recently was making a new character and I ctrl P and ctrl J the model , it appears that it made the armature the parent of the mesh as they did not join correctly and the rig will not join to the mesh now.

Comment: mmh, it's not clear at all, ctrl J is to merge 2 different mesh objects, it has nothing to do with armature, maybe show some screenshots?

Comment: worth reading: [parent to, confusing and misleading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101796/parent-to-confusing-and-misleading)

Comment: In general use, the rig is the parent of the mesh.  Alt-p armature deform will provide this relationship.  In reality, this relationship is basically meaningless.  A mesh doesn't need to be parented to a rig to be deformed by a rig.  However, if a rig's parent is a mesh that is deformed by that rig, you are creating a circular dependency, which is bad.  So don't do that.