# How can i attach objects to a mesh that has been displaced, without applying that displacement to the new objects

Tags: animation, mesh, displacement

I've created a simple displacement animation of a character with a body and two eyes. [image]

I want to attach the eyes to the body but because the body is displaced, the eyes follow that same displacement if i attach with CTRL-J.

[image]

How can i attach these two spheres to my main body without them following that displacement? It's almost like i want them to just sit on the skin of the object and move with it through the animation, but not change size or shape?

Comment: Have a look at vertex parenting, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects/26109#26109

Comment: Thanks so much!