# Grouping objects into a single object

Tags: groups

I've imported a Lego model into Blender. How do I group the parts together so I can transform them as a single unit? I don't want the individual parts to be selectable using the mouse. Thanks.

[edit]

I found the answer here:

[Is it possible to group several objects and then manipulate them (scale, rotate, translate) as one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105/is-it-possible-to-group-several-objects-and-then-manipulate-them-scale-rotate?rq=1)

So this is a duplicate.

Comment: Try join, Ctrl+J or space bar and type join