# Is there a way to move multiple objects away from each other without also scaling the size of the objects themselves?

Tags: scale, distort

I'm working on modeling a lamp that has a section near the bulb where instead of a straight pole connecting the base to the bulb, the pole divides into 8 parts and move apart and then together, while moving up. The problem I ran into is that the divided poles increase in size as I use the scale tool to move them apart, and there appears to be no option that I can find to fix it. All help would be appreciated. [image: All divided poles selected]

[image: Unwanted distortion of pole thickness]

Comment: See if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105/is-it-possible-to-group-several-objects-and-then-manipulate-them-scale-rotate

Comment: Use Extrude Individual. See Number 3 on this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7366/1853